# can i run apache storm without zookeeper in local mode?

Tags: apache-storm

I am running storm topology in local mode.

While running storm zookeeper and nimbus starts automaticaly

Is zookeeper and nimbus essential to run storm in local mode or can i stop it ? if so tel me how to stop it.

What is the role of zookeper in local mode while running storm in a single machine?

Comment: For local mode I guess you don't need actual zookeeper application to be running. Does your application throw any error if you didn't specify Zookeeper configuration?

Comment: actually i am running storm crawler,it is based on storm.i only imported storm as a jar.now i want to remove zookeeper from it.that is why i asked whether we need zookeeper

Comment: Whether it's a single machine or cluster, Zookeeper is necessary. Usually in local mode Storm uses internal zookeeper.

Comment: single machine only..and what do you mean by internal zookeeper? i can see zookeeper in storm core jar ..do you mean that?

Comment: Yes, Local mode will stimulate as cluster environment.

Comment: you mean, i need zookeeper to run storm even in local mode?

Comment: Yes, Storm has internal zookeeper/Nimbus services for simulating purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't disable Nimbus/Zookeeper. Zookeeper is an overall state management/coordination application which Storm uses for maintaining states and other information. Nimbus is like a master which accepts Storm job & schedules to downstream Supervisors. Storm need to use it's components like "Zookeeper" coordination service, "Nimbus" master & "Supervisor" slave to work. This is necessary in Local mode which will simulate Nimbus,Supervisor & Zookeeper services.

Comment: what if i run storm in multiple machines (pseudo-distributed mode). In that case do i have to install zookeeper in my machine?

Comment: If you submit your topology in real cluster then you must have at-least 1 zookeeper service running on any machine.

Comment: zookeeper service mean can i use it as a jar or i need to install it in my machine

Comment: You have to download & install Zookeeper application.